# How to bind external interface to internal interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an interface file as a `IAccount` and I must to call external interface which in a external DLL that it's name is `IAccount.How can I bind External interface to internal interface?Is it possible or no?
my code is :

```
 using IAccount = Accounts.DAL.IAccount;
 public Task<IAccount> AuthenticateAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        ISession session = null;
        Task<Mabna.AccountsSDK.IAccount> objAccount;
        var objAccountsSdk = new Mabna.AccountsSDK.Client(session);

        var some = (IAccount) objAccountsSdk.AccountManager.AuthenticateAsync(username, password);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "bind"? It isn't clear, what are you trying to do.

Comment: I want to map external interface to my interface

Comment: Are interface declarations identical? If answer is "yes", then why do you need your own interface? If "no", can you inherit your interface from external one?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to **wrap the external interface using your own.** You could use the [Adapter design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). The Adaptee class is the external referenced interface and your own interface would be implemented by the Adaptor. Then you could use your interface by instantiating the Adaptor class.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Look at (it's old school)--> `Activator.CreateInstanceFrom()`